# Why are the two dot product definitions equal?

Tags: geometry, vectors, inner-products

I have an intuitive understanding of why $a\dot{}b=|a||b|\cos{\theta}$ geometrically. The projection of one vector onto another makes sense to me when explaining the origin of this geometric definition.

What I don't understand is why $a\dot{}b=a_xb_x + a_yb_y = |a||b|\cos{\theta}$. How does the algebraic version of the dot product connect to the geometric version? Can you derive the algebraic definition from the geometric? I read the answers [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509719/proof-of-equivalence-of-algebraic-and-geometric-dot-product), but the proofs seem to depend on the actual algebraic definition to arrive at it.

My main question is, why are the two definitions *really* equal?

Comment: Can you prove it in two dimensions? Also, some places this is taken as the definition of angles in higher dimensions. So it's not a matter of proving that this is the case, but rather that $\theta$ is defined so that it works.

Comment: You can find a proof of $a\cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta$, if that's helpful for you, here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product

Comment: @Edu  So the geometric version is derived from the algebraic, not the other way around?

Comment: Geometrically, consider the triangle formed by the vectors $a$, $b$, and $a-b$ (where we think of $a$ and $b$ having a common origin, and the origin of $a-b$ placed at the end of $a$).  This triangle has sides of length $\|a\| = a\cdot a$, $\|b\| = b\cdot b$, and $\|a-b\| = (a-b)\cdot (a-b) = a\cdot a - 2a\cdot b + b\cdot b$.  Play with the Law of Cosines, and you should get what you want.

Comment: Absolutely. The dot product is a particular case of an *inner product*. For the Euclidean dot product you have this formula, which is slightly different for complex vectors, for instance.

Comment: This identity only holds for certain types of coordinate systems (bases) of the space.

Comment: A relevant, different perspective to answering this question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyGKycYT2v0

Answer (score 14):

Note that with $a$ and $b$ two sides of a triangle and $\theta$ the angle between them, the third side is $b-a$ and (cosine rule)  $$|b-a|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos \theta$$ so that $$2|a||b|\cos\theta=\Sigma a_i^2+\Sigma b_i^2-\Sigma (b_i-a_i)^2=2\Sigma a_ib_i$$ so that $$|a||b|\cos\theta=\Sigma a_ib_i$$ and the two definitions coincide. You can work the calculations backwards if necessary.

Comment: You are missing the case in which $a$ and $b$ are scalar multiples.

Comment: @Edu then $\cos \theta=1$ and everything works? The cosine rule applies to the degenerate triangle you get.

Comment: Of course, is a trivial case, no problems with your proof, not even close to think about downvoting or something. I just think is worth it mention what happens if $a=cb$, for some scalar $c$.

Comment: Btw, $\cos\theta=\pm 1$ in that case, depending on the sign of $c$.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you can prove from the geometrical definition that distributive property holds for scalar product: $(\vec a+\vec b)\cdot\vec c=\vec a\cdot\vec c+\vec b\cdot\vec c$ (see diagram below for a sketch of the proof).

[image]

Then, you just have to decompose two vectors along an **orthonormal** coordinate system: $\vec a= a_x\vec i+a_y\vec j+a_z\vec k$,$\quad$ $\vec b= b_x\vec i+b_y\vec j+b_z\vec k$, and apply twice the distributive property, taking into account that $\vec i\cdot\vec i=\vec j\cdot\vec j=\vec k\cdot\vec k=1$
and $\vec i\cdot\vec j=\vec j\cdot\vec k=\vec k\cdot\vec i=0$:
$$
\vec a\cdot\vec b=
(a_x\vec i+a_y\vec j+a_z\vec k)\cdot(b_x\vec i+b_y\vec j+b_z\vec k)=
a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos( \theta)$

and that $|a| = \sqrt{(x_1)^2 + (y_1)^2}$

and that $|b| = \sqrt{(x_2)^2 + (y_2)^2}$

Let $\gamma -\theta = \alpha$

For $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors, $a$ and $b$, and not necessarily the angle between the 'outermost' line and say the x-axis.

Thus $\gamma$ is the angle between the outermost vector and the x-axis, whilst $\alpha$ is the angle between the other line and the x-axis.

Thus $\theta=\gamma-\alpha$ and more importantly by the trig identity: $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a\cdot b &= |a||b|\cos(\theta)\\
&=|a||b|\cos(\gamma - \alpha)\\
&=|a||b|\biggl(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)\biggl)\\
&=|a||b|\cos(\gamma)\cos(-\alpha) - |a||b|\sin(\gamma)\sin(-\alpha)\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}$$

Then if $|a|$ was the outermost vector you realize that

$|a|\cos(\gamma) = (x_1)$, and that

$|a|\sin(\gamma) = (y_1)$

Making $|b|$ the innermost line, and that

$|b|\cos(-\alpha) = |b|\cos(\alpha) = (x_2)$, and that

$|b|\sin(-\alpha) = -|b|\sin(\alpha) = (-y_1)$

Because $\cos(-a) = \cos(a)$ and $\sin(-a) = -\sin(a)$

Plugging all that into 1 you get that $a\cdot b = (x_1)(x_2) - (y_1)(-y_2)$

And you finally get $a\cdot b = (x_1)(x_2) + (y_1)(y_2)$

Answer (score 0):

Define A, B, C is vector, and a, b and c scale value (distance) of A,B,C 
define C=A-B, so A, B and C become a triangle

based on Law of cosines, c² = a² + b² - 2abcos(θ)

because c.c=C²
 C.C=A.A + B.B - 2abcos(θ)
because C = A - B
 C·C => (A -B)·(A - B) => (A·A - 2A·B + B·B)
so A·A - 2A·B + B·B=A.A + B.B - 2abcos(θ)
because A.A=A.A and B.B=B.B
=> - 2A·B B=- 2abcos(θ)
=> A.B=abcos(θ)

Comment: Try to use math formatting for better readability. See [notation help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thanks I just joined this community, I will try to use the math formatting next time