# How do you prove the equivalence for algebraic and geometric definition for both dot and cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cross-product

How do the algebraic and geometric formulas of dot and cross product relate to each other? I have seen the proof for 2 dimensions but how do we generalize it to $n$ dimensions? Is there a way to prove it without the cosine law? That proof feels like a chicken and egg proof as some use vectors to prove cosine rule and vice versa.

Proof for 2 dimensions: [Proof of equivalence of algebraic and geometric dot product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509719/proof-of-equivalence-of-algebraic-and-geometric-dot-product#)

Comment: $n=2$ is enough; the identity holds (appropriately formulated) for every $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so just consider the subspace spanned by the two vectors in question.

Comment: I don’t think you can generalize to $n$ dimensions. For one thing, the cross product doesn’t make sense in $n$ dimensions (for most values of $n$). Generalizing to $n=3$ dimensions makes sense. But, as the other comment points out, you’ll really be working in the 2D sub space spanned by the two vectors.

Comment: Sorry, how do you generalise the proof of equivalence for dot product to n dimensions?