# Why is the SVM margin equal to $\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I am reading the Wikipedia article about [Support Vector Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) and I don't understand how they compute the distance between two hyperplanes.

In the article,

> By using geometry, we find the distance between these two hyperplanes
>   is $\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$

I don't understand how the find that result.

[image: is a link to the image]

### What I tried

I tried setting up an example in two dimensions with an hyperplane having the equation $y = -2x+5$ and separating some points $A(2,0)$, $B(3,0)$ and $C(0,4)$, $D(0,6)$ .

If I take a vector $\mathbf{w}(-2,-1)$ normal to that hyperplane and compute the margin with $\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$ I get $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ when in my example the margin is equal to 2 (distance between $C$ and $D$).

**How did they come up with $\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$** ?

Comment: You mean $y=-2x+5$, it seems. And the margin is probably related to the maximum distance between two parallel hyperplanes that can separate the two point sets; it is not a distance between points of the datasets.

Comment: @ccom Thanks I corrected the formula. Yes but the two points of the dataset I choose are on the parallel hyperplanes so it should be the same I think.

Comment: I found out my error. I was using two points but the line passing though them is not perpendicular to the hyperplane.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let $\textbf{x}_0$ be a point in the hyperplane $\textbf{wx} - b = -1$, i.e., $\textbf{wx}_0 - b = -1$. To measure the distance between hyperplanes $\textbf{wx}-b=-1$ and $\textbf{wx}-b=1$, we only need to compute the perpendicular distance from $\textbf{x}_0$ to plane $\textbf{wx}-b=1$, denoted as $r$.

Note that $\frac{\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|}$ is a unit normal vector of the hyperplane $\textbf{wx}-b=1$. We have
$$
\textbf{w}(\textbf{x}_0 + r\frac{\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|}) - b = 1
$$
since $\textbf{x}_0 + r\frac{\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|}$ should be a point in hyperplane $\textbf{wx}-b = 1$ according to our definition of $r$.

Expanding this equation, we have
\begin{align*}
& \textbf{wx}_0 + r\frac{\textbf{w}\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|} - b = 1 \\
\implies &\textbf{wx}_0 + r\frac{\|\textbf{w}\|^2}{\|\textbf{w}\|} - b = 1 \\
\implies &\textbf{wx}_0 + r\|\textbf{w}\| - b = 1 \\
\implies &\textbf{wx}_0 - b = 1 - r\|\textbf{w}\| \\ 
\implies &-1 = 1 - r\|\textbf{w}\|\\
\implies & r = \frac{2}{\|\textbf{w}\|}
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice! Thank you

Comment: Here's a video of Patrick Winston explaining an even simpler derivation: https://youtu.be/_PwhiWxHK8o?t=1020

Answer (score 18):

[image: SVM]

Let $\textbf{x}_+$ be a positive example on one gutter, such that
$$\textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{x}_+ - b = 1$$

Let $\textbf{x}_-$ be a negative example on another gutter, such that $$\textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{x}_- - b = -1$$

The width of margin is the [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) of $\textbf{x}_+ - \textbf{x}_-$ on unit normal vector , that is the dot production of $\textbf{x}_+ - \textbf{x}_-$ and $\frac{\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|}$

\begin{align}
width & = (\textbf{x}_+ - \textbf{x}_-) \cdot \frac{\textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|} \\
      & = \frac {(\textbf{x}_+ - \textbf{x}_-) \cdot {\textbf{w}}}{\|\textbf{w}\|} \\
      & = \frac{\textbf{x}_+ \cdot \textbf{w} \,{\bf -}\, \textbf{x}_-\cdot \textbf{w}}{\|\textbf{w}\|} \\
      & = \frac{1-b-(-1-b)}{\lVert \textbf{w} \rVert} \\
      & = \frac{2}{\|\textbf{w}\|}
\end{align}

The above refers to [MIT 6.034 Artificial Intelligence](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/lecture-videos/lecture-16-learning-support-vector-machines/)

Comment: This answer is way better than the accepted one....

Comment: Found these two links quite useful when you struggle with the dot product intuition here like I did [scalar projection from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) and [dot production intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1730547/851242)

Answer (score 1):

The margin equals the shortest distance between the points of the two hyperplanes. Let $\mathbf{x_1}$ be a point of one hyperplane, and $\mathbf{x}_2$ be a point of the other hyperplane.
We want to find the minimal value of $\lVert \mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2 \rVert$.
Since
\begin{align}
\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}_1 - b &= 1,\\
\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}_2 - b &= -1,
\end{align}
we have
$$\mathbf{w}\cdot(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2) = 2.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert \lVert \mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2 \rVert \geq 2,$$
and therefore
$$\lVert \mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2 \rVert \geq \frac{2}{\lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert },$$
where equality holds when $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2$ are linearly dependent (which is clearly always possible).