# Rotations - linear or quadratic?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

In linear algebra rotations are represented by matrices, i.e. linear transformations

[How do you formally prove that rotation is a linear transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/how-do-you-formally-prove-that-rotation-is-a-linear-transformation)

But this page is very interesting

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/theory/

it vaguely talks about rotations as being quadratic in the way that the length of a vector is quadratic

[image]

then it also shows how a rotation takes in something quadratic and spits out something linear

[image]

but it also vaguely hints that the 'quadratic-ness' as being encoded in rotating your basis vectors

[image]

**Is there a way to make all this precise with rigorous linear operators, bilinear and quadratic forms etc...?**

It's very hand-wavey, but cool if correct.

I'm guessing this 'quadratic' business means tensors, bilinear forms etc... so I guess they're saying that all the rotation matrices, unitary geometry etc... is properly thought of as part of bilinear algebra rather than linear algebra - make sense?

Comment: A linear transformation $A$ satisfies $A(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) = A(\vec{x}) + A(\vec{x}y)$ and $A(a\vec{x}) = a A(\vec{x})$...

Comment: To me this so-called "quadraticness" is just related to the fact that the rotation matrix has complex eigenvalues. There's a nice book on the topic from Simon Altmann called Rotations, Quaternions and Double Groups.

Comment: Someone doesn't know how to spell "intuitive".

Answer (score 2):

A rotation satisfies $A(x+y)=A(x)+A(y)$ and $A(ax)=aA(x)$, therefore it is a linear transformation (shamelessly stolen from johannesvalks).

Furthermore, the length of a vector is *not* "quadratic". There's a square root in there that makes it non-quadratic. It's only the square of the length of a vector that is quadratic, but that's not what we're talking about.