# Understanding why the definition $\cos(\widehat{vw})=\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\| \|w\|} $ works so well.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

After perusing several geometry / vector space posts on the forum to better understand formal notions of angles and rotations, while avoiding circularity, I came across a definition that I really like from [How do you formally prove that rotation is a linear transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/how-do-you-formally-prove-that-rotation-is-a-linear-transformation) :

$$\cos(\widehat{vw})=\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\| \|w\|} $$

After playing around with this definition, I noticed that one of the properties this definition (obviously quite purposefully) possesses is that holding $w$ constant, one can vary the *length* (but not 'direction') of $v$ without changing the value of the expression (which adheres to our intuitive notion of an 'angle' between two vectors).

I am going through the Chapter 4 appendices of Spivak's *Calculus*, so I have not yet really even transitioned into any notion of derivative/rates of change, etc. I was wondering if an analytical justification for my observation can be stated without using calculus.

More or less, I am wondering if I can gain insight into why the value of the expression is independent of the length of $v$.

Perhaps the very nature of this question cannot be answered without a nod to calculus, in which case, my apologies for the poorly posed question.

---

Edit 1:

It seems like the idea here is that, treating the dot product as a function, $\cdot(v,w)$ and $\sqrt{\cdot(v,v)}\sqrt{\cdot (w,w)}$ change equally while varying the length of $v$.

---

Edit 2:

After some thinking, one can reduce my argument to:

**Prove** $\cos \big ( \widehat{(\alpha v)w})=\cos(\widehat{vw})$ for any scalar $\alpha$.

Applying the definition: $\cos \big ( \widehat{(\alpha v)w})=\dfrac{(\alpha v) \cdot w}{\lVert \alpha v \rVert \lVert w \rVert}$

From properties of norms and dot products, we know the following:

$(\alpha v) \cdot w=\alpha(v \cdot w)$

$\lVert \alpha v \rVert = \alpha \lVert v \rVert$

Applying these two properties, we get:

$\dfrac{(\alpha v) \cdot w}{\lVert \alpha v \rVert \lVert w \rVert} = \dfrac{\alpha (v \cdot w)}{\alpha \lVert v \rVert \lVert w \rVert}$

Canceling out the $\alpha$'s, the answer follows.

Using the same approach, we can further generalize this to:

$\cos \big ( \widehat{(\alpha v)(\beta w})=\cos(\widehat{vw})$ for any scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Define "good.".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork hah, fair point. I really just want to know if my observation can be explained formally without calculus. Alternatively, maybe a better framing is "why is the value of the expression independent of the length of $v$"

Comment: Since this is $\frac{v}{\|v\|}\cdot\frac{w}{\|w\|}$, you're really asking why $v/\|v\|$ doesn't depend on $\|v\|$...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork :I guess you weren't here after I posted my answer, since you would have downvoted it if you were paying attention. But I've fixed it now.

Comment: In MathJax and in LaTeX, you should use `\cos` rather than `\text{cos}` because only the former has context-dependent spacing. Thus in $\cos x$ and $cos (x),$ coded as `\cos x` and `\cos (x)`, you see less space to the right of $\cos$ in the second expression than in the first, and $2\cos x,$ coded as `2\cos x` looks different from $2\text{cos} x,$ coded as `2\text{cos} x`, in that the latter lacks proper spacing. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy rodger that. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer : Clumsy typo: I should have written $\cos(x)$ rather than $cos(x). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to believe that two vectors are orthogonal to each other iff their dot product is $0,$ then consider this:

By computing the dot product, one can see that

- $\dfrac{u\cdot v}{\|v\|\|v\|} v$ and $u - \dfrac{u\cdot v}{\|v\|\|v\|} v$ are orthogonal to each other, and
- the first of the two vectors above is in the direction of $v,$ and
- the sum of those two vectors is $u.$

Thus we have a right triangle in which the adjacent side is $\dfrac{u\cdot v}{\|v\|\|v\|} v$ and the hypotenuse is $u$. The cosine is the length of the adjacent side divide by the length of the hypotenuse.

Comment: Assuming I am following you in the right direction, we're making use of the fact that $\lVert \alpha \mathbf{v} \rVert = \alpha \lVert \mathbf{v} \rVert$, right? In which case, we have $\text{cos}(\theta)=\dfrac{u\cdot v}{\|u\|\|v\|} \frac{\lVert v \rVert}{\lVert  u \rVert}$, which equals $\dfrac{u \cdot v}{u \cdot u}$. Is that correct? If so, don't we still have a $v$ dependency? (Sorry if I am missing something)

Comment: I think I understand the point you are trying to make, namely that the *norm* of $v$ is no longer part of the equation. But the expression $\dfrac {u \cdot v}{u \cdot u}$ would make me ask the question, "Why does this new expression remain constant while varying the length of $v$"? The dot product is necessarily dependent on a vector's length, right? Due to your definitions, a change to length $v$ will change the length to $u$. So why does a change in $v$ change *equally* the expressions $u \cdot v$ and $u \cdot u$

Comment: @S.Cramer : Sorry: I messed up a detail, whose correction unfortunately will require you to go back to square one. I've fixed it now.

Comment: thank you for the response! I'll look through the answer soon. Much appreciated. Cheers~

Comment: Is the idea that this definition ultimately reduces to the dot product of unit vectors?

Comment: @S.Cramer : It does that, but that's not the whole story: One thinks about orthogonal projections and about adjacent-over-hypotenuse.

Comment: I placed a solution under my "Edit 2" section, which I think addresses my question. I am therefore a little curious as to what exactly I should be *taking away* from your proof (because I am assuming it is something meaningful that would improve my overall understanding). Sorry for the inconvenience!