# Simplify $\tan^{-1}[(\cos x - \sin x)/(\cos x + \sin x)]$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

> Write the following functions in simplest form:
>     $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\right), \quad 0<x<\pi$$

Please help me to solve this problem. I have been trying to solve this from last 3 hours. I can solve simple inverse trigonometric functions

Comment: define *simplest* please.

Comment: It would be nice if it had the form $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\cdots)}{\cos(\cdots)}\right)$, wouldn't it? See if you can use rewritings like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181676/how-to-see-sin-x-cos-x/181841#181841) to make it so.

Answer (score 4):

Let's multiply the numerator and denominator by $\ \cos\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)=\sin\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\ $ :
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\cos(x)-\cos\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\sin(x)}{\cos\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\cos(x)+\sin\bigl(\frac {\pi}4\bigr)\sin(x)}\right),\quad 0<x<\pi$$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac {\pi}4-x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac {\pi}4-x\right)}\right),\quad 0<x<\pi$$
$$=\begin{cases}
&\frac {\pi}4-x&\quad\text{if}\ \ 0 < x < \frac{3\pi}4\\
&\text{not defined}&\quad\text{if}\quad x = \frac{3\pi}4\\
&\frac {5\pi}4-x&\quad\text{if}\ \ \frac{3\pi}4< x < \pi\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta=\tan^{-1}(X)$ where $X=\left(\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\right)$ and $0<x<\pi$ ,we have $$\frac{1-X}{1+X}=\tan(x)$$ But $\tan(\theta)=X$ so, $\tan(x)=\frac{1-\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan(\theta)}=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta)$. The rest is as Raymond concluded above.

Comment: Nice $\checkmark\quad\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\right),\quad 0<x<\pi$$

$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\right)$ diving  the numerator and denominator by $\cos x$

$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}-\tan(x)}{1+\tan\frac{\pi}{4}\tan(x)}\right)$ as $\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$

$=\tan^{-1}\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)$

$=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}-x$  where n is any integer.

The principal value which must lie in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$,
 will be

$\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ when $\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ lies in that region i.e, $\frac{3\pi}{4}  ≥ x  > -\frac{\pi}{4}$

and   $\pi +\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ elsewhere.

But $0<x<\pi$,

so, if  $\frac{\pi}{2}  ≥ x  ≥ 0$ the principal value =$\frac{\pi}{4}-x$

and  $\frac{5\pi}{4}-x$ elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

It is  $\tan  ^{-1}\dfrac{\cos  \left(x\right)-\sin  \left(x\right)}{\cos  \left(x\right)+\sin  \left(x\right)}$

We will divide in bracket with cosx to get it in tan form which will be easy for us to simplify

$\implies \tan  ^{-1}\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos  \left(x\right)-\sin  \left(x\right)}{\cos  \left(x\right)}}{\dfrac{\cos  \left(x\right)-\sin  \left(x\right)}{\cos  \left(x\right)}}$

$\implies \tan  ^{-1}\dfrac{1-\tan  \left(x\right)}{1+\cos  \left(x\right)}$

Now we know that $\tan  ^{-1}x + \tan  ^{-1}y= \dfrac{x-y}{1-xy}$ when $xy<1$

and we have the bracket in the same form as $\dfrac{\tan  \left(1\right)-\tan  \left(x\right)}{1-\tan  \left(1\right)\tan  \left(x\right)}$

So we get $\tan  ^{-1} \left(\tan   \left(\dfrac{π}{4}\right) + \tan   \left(X\right)\right)$
i.e $\dfrac{π}{4-x}$.