# How to rewrite $a\sin x+b\cos x$ just using $\sin x$ or $\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry

For $$\sin (x)+\sqrt{3} \cos (x)$$, we can rewrite it as $$2 \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)$$.

Is there a formula to represent $$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$$ just by using sine or cosine function just as the aforementioned example?

Comment: [This graphical explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/181841/14366) easily generalizes to the situation where lenghts $a$ and $b$ are not $1$.

Comment: I would guess is $/sqrt(a^2 + b^2)sen(x + atan (b/a))$. I cant remember very well but I suppose maybe you can prove it using $e^{ix} = cos x + i sen x $ and taking real and imaginary parts and somethings like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a \sin(x) + b\cos(x) = r \sin(x + \theta)$ where $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, $a/r = \cos(\theta)$ and $b/r = \sin(\theta)$.  Thus if $a > 0$, $\theta = \arcsin(b/r)$ while if $a < 0$, $\theta = \pi - \arcsin(b/r)$ will do.