# Arrange in ascending order $\tan45^\circ,\tan80^\circ$ and $\tan100^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

> Arrange in ascending order $\tan45^\circ,\tan80^\circ$ and $\tan100^\circ.$

We know that $\tan45^\circ=1$ because a right triangle with angle equal to $45^\circ$ is isosceles.
[image]

I don't know the exact values of $\tan80^\circ$ and $\tan 100^\circ.$ Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\tan x \lt 0$ for $90^\circ\lt x \lt 180^\circ$ and $\tan x$ is an increasing function on $[0,90^\circ)$.

[image]

$\tan \theta$ is defined to be the orange line in the diagram. What happens to this line as $\theta$ goes from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't see why $\tan x$ is an increasing function on $[0; 90^\circ).$

Comment: @nicoledobreva Do you know about calculus?

Comment: No, I don't know about calculus.

Comment: @nicoledobreva No need for calculus: in your drawing, fix the horizontal side, make the acute angle on the right grow, how does the vertical side change?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, it also grows, right?

Comment: @nicoledobreva Right, so the tangent is an increasing function of the angle (as long as the angle is in $(0,90)$)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That’s a nice way of showing it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\tan=\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$

$$\tan80^\circ-\tan45^\circ=\cdots=\dfrac{\sin(80-45)^\circ }{\cos80^\circ\cos45^\circ}>0$$

We know $\tan45^\circ=?$

and $\tan100^\circ=\tan(180^\circ-80^\circ)=-\tan80^\circ<0$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am on $\tan80^\circ-\tan45^\circ=\dfrac{\sin80^\circ\cos45^\circ-\sin45^\circ\cos80^\circ}{\cos80^\circ\cos45^\circ}$. Why is that equal to $\dfrac{\sin(80-45)^\circ }{\cos80^\circ\cos45^\circ}?$

Comment: @nicoledobreva, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705021/trigonometry-identity-prove-that-sina-b-sin-a-cos-b-cos-a-sin-b

Comment: Thank you! We are using the trig identity: $\sin(\alpha\pm\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta\pm\cos\alpha\sin\beta.$ We haven't studied it and the proof does not seem easy. So we have $\tan80^\circ-\tan45^\circ=\dfrac{\sin35^\circ}{\cos80^\circ\cos45^\circ}>0,$ right? Therefore, $\tan80^\circ>\tan45^\circ.$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(x)$ is defined on $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb Z} (90(2n-1), 90(2n+1))$ (when working in degrees) and increasing inside each such set.

Moreover, recall that $\tan(x)\equiv\tan(x+180k)$ for each $k\in \Bbb Z$

So, we may say that $\tan(x)$ is increasing on the range $(-90, 90)$, as seen when $n=0$, and $\tan(100)=\tan(-80)<\tan(45)<\tan(80)$

Comment: Thank you for the response!