# Noob question: Why do trignometric functions repeat on a graph?

Tags: trigonometry

When a sine wave (or a cosine wave) is graphed, it repeats itself at a fixed period. However, the value $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is geometrically undefined because you can't have a triangle with two right angles. The same argument is true for all obtuse angles. So why do we still graph these and use these values as valid inputs to trignometric functions?

Comment: Google "unit circle"

Comment: That depends on how you *define* the sine function in the first place.  It is useful to us to define sine from an analytical point of view as $\sin(z):=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\dots=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$.  From that perspective, any input makes sense to talk about, even complex inputs.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes, I do know that sine and cosine can be defined as the y and x coordinates as you go through points on a circle. However, it still doesn't make sense using the original definition.

Comment: So your question isn't really about repeating, as much as it is "Why did we switch from triangles to the unit circle?"

Comment: @u8y7541 The original definition can be seen as a being *special case* of the unit circle definition. Since the original definition agrees with the unit circle definition for angles in the range $(0, \pi/2)$, it is natural to use the unit circle to extend the definition of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: It looks like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794201/why-does-sin0-exist?rq=1) (*was located on the related bar to the right*) should contain a lot of the information you are looking for.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, reading it was helpful.

Comment: Why do you think triangles is the "original" definition?  I was taught with circles first and it always made more sense to me.  Anyway "original" definition is irrelevent.  It wasn't good enough because you can't have two right angles.  So we made it *better*.  The physical actual side of triangle and the right angle have nothing to do with anything, so we shouldn't let them trip us up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to define sin and cos using the unit circle, then you can have a function with more values which can still be used to make inferences about right angled triangles. Any theorems proven about sin will then be applicable to the specific cases where the angles involved are less than 90 degrees.

A function $f$ which agrees with another function $g$ on a smaller domain is called an extension of $f$. Finding extensions of functions with nice properties to larger domains (where they still retain some/all nice properties of the 'original' function) is a common theme in mathematics. Extending sin and cos to the unit circle is an example of this.