# Help me prove: sin(A+B) = sinA cosB + cosA sinB

Tags: trigonometry

Can you help me prove that: sin(A+B) = sinA cosB + cosA sinB?

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856757).

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/856780/81360), in particular.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry/1342#1342) also has several helpful answers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are  two for the price of one (using Euler's formula):

$$\color{red}{\cos(A+B)}+i\color{green}{\sin(A+B)} \equiv e^{i(A+B)} \equiv e^{iA} \times e^{iB}$$
$$\equiv [\cos(A)+i\sin(A)][\cos(B)+i\sin(B)]$$
$$\equiv \color{red}{[\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)]}+i\color{green}{[\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)]}$$

Now equate imaginary parts to give the result for $\sin(A+B)$ (and, if you want, equate real parts to give the result for $\cos(A+B)$).

Comment: Isnt this circular ? How for example do you prove $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x$?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus How is it circular? The fact that $e^{ix} \equiv \cos(x)+i \sin(x)$ does not rely on the statement posed by the OP.

Comment: Oh I guess you do that from the power series definition

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yep, and there are many more proofs! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula#Proofs .

Comment: There are some derivations of Eulers formula which rely on the sum formula.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Ah- I didn't know that. Do you have a link to such a proof?

Comment: No link, but if you use DeMoivre's formula and the limit definition of $e^x$ you can see how its done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write it as $\sin(x) = 1/2 i e^{-i x} - 1/2 i e^{i x}$

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm still pretty new to math; do you think you can write out your proof all the way? I think I get where you're going, but I'm not totally sure. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a very interesting geometric proof [here](http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/sum-proof.htm).
It proves it relatively clearly and concisely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof without using complex numbers, from Apostol.

$$\sin(x+y) = -\cos(x + y + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\cos x\cos(y + \frac{\pi}{2}) + \sin(x)\ \sin(y + \frac{\pi}{2})$$

$$= \cos x\ \sin y + \sin x\cos y $$

Assuming you can prove the formula for the cosine, of course, which Apostol gives as a property of the cosine.

Answer (score -3):

May be a little unconventional, but assuming we have an isosceles right angled triangle.

Then, $sin 90^\circ=1$

$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$=cos 45^\circ \cdot sin 45^\circ+sin 45^\circ \cdot cos 45^\circ$$

The similar can be proved for a scalene triangle as well.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything in general, though....