# Using Euler's formula derive the following formula:

Tags: complex-analysis

$\cos2a=\cos^2a-\sin^2a$

I know that euler's formula is $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$

$$ (e^{ia})^2 = \cos^2a-\sin^2a+2i\sin(a)\cos(a) $$

where would I go from here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Did you mean $(e^{i\color{red}a})^2=\cos^2(a)\color{red}-\sin^2(a)+2i\sin(a)\cos(a)$?

Comment: Yes I did! Thank you, ill fix that

Comment: From there, you could take the real part of both sides.  Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856757/why-is-cos2x-cos2x-sin2x-and-sin2x-2-sinx-cosx)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In my opinion, the offered proofs of the angle sum identities have the defect of assuming that the angles $~\alpha, \beta, ~$ and $~(\alpha + \beta)~$ are all acute angles.  Agreed that consideration of obtuse angles is ugly; however it is necessary and I have never seen any attempt to consider the obtuse angles.