# What is your best way to memorize results for common arguments of trigonometric functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Especially looking at sine and cosine here. I'm trying to learn them by heart and it's quite unintuitive for me. If you guys could tell me about your way, be it by drawing up something or a table, I'd be glad to hear you guys suggestions :))

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1553990/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/877121/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1352996/42969

Answer (score 1):

The values for sine of 0, 30, 45, 60, and 90 degrees (of course in "real" maths we don't use degrees, but this is how I learnt it when I first encountered trigonometric functions) are $\frac12\sqrt0$, $\frac12\sqrt1$, $\frac12\sqrt2$, $\frac12\sqrt3$, $\frac12\sqrt4$. For cosine you go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Very nice; also, these are (roughly speaking) the only ones you should need to memorize.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I saw this in some book a long time ago.