# Sine Subtraction Law - a Geomtrical Proof

Tags: trigonometry

I can't solve the following problem (From the book: The Forgotten Art of Spherical Trigonometry):

[image]

I can't manage to prov it geometrically.

I could get that I have to find AB and the values indicated in the diagram.
I also think that D angle in DCE is equal to alpha as B in BED is, making DCE and BED similar, but then I always get very complicated calculation when I try to give a dimension to CE or DC.

How it is the smart way?

Thanks

Comment: FYI: [My answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409) provides alternative diagrams for the sum and difference formulas.

Comment: @Blue Those are a lot simpler!  I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $DEAO$ is a parallelogram, $\angle CDE = \alpha$.

Since $\angle DEB$ is a right angle, $\angle EBD = \alpha.$

From there you can calculate $CD, DE, CE$.

Then, by writing down $CA = CE + EB + BA,$

$$\sin \alpha (\cos \beta + \tan \alpha \sin \beta) = \sin \alpha \tan \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta + \sin(\alpha - \beta),$$

the result follows by algebra.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Sine is an odd function so $$\sin(-\beta) = -\sin(\beta)$$

Comment: I think the question looks for the geometric solution (b).  You gave the correct way to solve (a).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$AB = DF - BE $$

where:

$AB = OB\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin(\alpha - \beta)$

$DF = OD\sin \alpha = \cos\beta\sin\alpha$

$BE = BD\cos \alpha = \sin\beta\cos\alpha$