# Simplifying the expression $2\cos^{2}6x-1$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to simplify the expression $2\cos^{2}6x-1$.

The book got the answer of $\cos 12 x$ by doing $2\cos^{2}6x-1 = \cos2\left(6x\right) = \cos12x$

It said the double angle is $12x$. I don't know how $2\cos^{2}6x-1$ got to $\cos2\left(6x\right)$, can anyone explain how this works?

It said it used cosine of double-angle formula, but I am not sure how it got the answer.

Comment: Do you know what the cosine double angle formula is? It's easily available through google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove the cosine double angle identities, we need the sum identity for cosine. That is, $\cos(x+y) = \cos x\cos y - \sin x \sin y.$ For a proof of this, see the picture below.

Now taking $y=x$, we get $\cos(2x) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$. Now since $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, we have $\cos(2x) = \cos^2x - (1-\cos^2 x)$.

Simplifying, we have $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2x - 1.$

---

[image]

Comment: [Credit to the original author](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/225981)

Comment: @MonkeyKing Thanks! I didn't know those came from here. This is my favorite proof of the identities!

Comment: And "Sine, Cosine, Sign, Cosine, Sine!
Cosine, Cosine, Co-Sign, Sine, Sine!" is my most favorite rhyme! (My memory is extremely poor, but this rhyme actually works!)

Answer (score 5):

Take
$$\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$$
and substitute $\theta=6x$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1$$
Since $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

I get:

$$2cos^2(6x)-1=cos(12x)$$

Verify the identity:

$$2*\frac{1+cos(12x)}{2}-1{=}cos(12x)$$
$$1+cos(12x)-1=cos(12x)$$
$$cos(12x)=cos(12x)$$

Now the left hand side and right hand side are identitcal!