# Show $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ with the circle.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that $$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$ using the circle ?

Comment: Here's a proof: http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/173/idns-proof.pdf

Comment: What does it mean to prove something "with the circle"?

Comment: @HowDoIMath: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry

Comment: And do you have something to show with the circle that $\cos a+\cos b=2\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z_1=\cos a + i\sin a$ and $z_2=\cos b + i\sin b$ then
$$
\eqalign{
z_1 \cdot z_2 &= (\cos a + i\sin a)\cdot(\cos b + i\sin b) \cr
           &= (\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b) + i(\cos a \sin b + \sin a \cos b) \cr
}
$$
we conclude 
$$
\cases{
\cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b \cr
\sin(a+b) = \cos a \sin b + \sin a \cos b \cr
}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I know that the OP is requesting a geometrical demonstration, but I thought that it would be instructive to see a couple of other approaches.

**METHOD 1:**

Let $f(x)$ be the function given by

$$f(x)=\cos x \cos(y-x)-\sin x \sin (y-x) \tag 1$$

Differentiating $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\sin x\cos (y-x)+\cos x \sin (y-x)-\cos x \sin (y-x)+\sin x \cos (y-x)\\\\
&=0
\end{align} $$

Therefore $f$ is a constant for all $x$.

First, letting $y=a+b$ and $x=0$ in $(1)$ shows that

$$f=\cos (a+b) \tag 2$$

Then, letting $y=a+b$ and $x=a$ in $(1)$ shows that

$$f=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b \tag 3$$

Equating $(2)$ and $(3)$ reveals that

$$\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHOD 2:**

Using Euler's Identity $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we have

$$e^{i(a+b)}=\cos (a+b)+i\sin(a+b) \tag 1$$

and

$$\begin{align}
e^{i(a+b)}&=e^{ia}e^{ib}\\\\
&=(\cos a+i\sin a)(\cos b+i\sin b)\\\\
&=(\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b)+i(\sin a \cos b\cos a \sin b)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Equating real and imaginary parts of $(1)$ and $(2)$, respectively, reveals

$$\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b$$

and

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b\cos a \sin b$$

as expected!

Answer (score 1):

I usually forget this kind of identities, so I have found that it is easy to get some of them writing sine and cosine as complex exponentials. In this case we have:
$$\cos(a+b)=\frac{e^{i(a+b)}+e^{-i(a+b)}}{2}=\frac{e^{ia}e^{ib}+e^{-ia}e^{-ib}}{2}=$$ $$=\frac{(\cos a+i \sin a)(\cos b +i \sin b)+(\cos a - i \sin a)(\cos b - i \sin b)}{2}=$$ $$=\frac{\cos a \cos b + i \sin a \cos b + i \cos a \sin b -\sin a \sin b}{2}+\frac{\cos a \cos b - i \sin a \cos b - i \cos a \sin b -\sin a \sin b}{2}=$$ $$=\frac{2\cos a \cos b -2 \sin a \sin b }{2}= \cos {a} \cos {b} + \sin{ a} \sin {b}$$

PS: Sorry, I didn't read the part that said "using the circle", so this is not what you are looking for. Anyway, I leave it here in the case it is useful as an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the point of coordinates $(\cos a, \sin a)$ around the origin with the rotation of angle $b$ using the matrix $$R(0,b)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos b & -\sin b\\
\sin b & \cos b \end{pmatrix}$$