# Deriving the sin and cos addition formulas using Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function, proof-explanation

I am trying to figure out the quick way to remember the addition formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ using Euler's formula:

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha + \beta) &= \sin \alpha\;\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\;\sin\beta \\
\cos(\alpha + \beta) &= \cos \alpha\;\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\;\sin\beta \\
\sin(\alpha-\beta) &= \sin\alpha\;\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\;\sin\beta \\
\cos(\alpha-\beta) &= \cos\alpha\;\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\;\sin\beta
\end{align}$$

I'm now convinced of why it is true that $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ but I don't know how to use this to derive these four rules.

Comment: Calculate $e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}$ and $e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}$ using the fact that $e^{i(x+y)} = e^{ix}e^{iy}$

Comment: If you're looking for a way to remember the identities, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409) may help.

Comment: @Blue I did see that post but it almost seems like a ton more to remember than just trying to brute memorize the formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$
$$Re\{e^{i(x+y)}\}=\cos(x+y)$$
$$=Re\{e^{ix}e^{iy}\}$$
$$=Re\{(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos y+i\sin y)\}$$
$$=Re\{\cos x\cos y+i(\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x)-\sin y\sin x\}$$
$$=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$$

$$Im\{e^{i(x+y)}\}=\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x$$

You can apply a similar reasoning to all the other ones, just working with the laws of exponents and comparing the real and imaginary parts.

As for why $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ applies, this is commonly understood by considering the Taylor series expansions of $e^{ix}$ and comparing it with that of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Comment: What about subtraction? Do you have to divide these?

Comment: Nope, just write $\cos (-x)+i\sin(-x)=\cos x-i\sin x$ as cosine is even, sine is off.

Comment: But the lefthand side is still $e^{ix} / e^{iy}$?

Comment: $e^{i(x-y)}=e^{ix}\times e^{-iy}=(\cos x + i\sin x)(\cos y-i\sin y)$

Comment: Can the tangent addition/subtraction formulas be extracted from this somehow too or is that a separate thing?