# Understanding this proof for $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ from Gelfand

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-explanation

We would like to have a small question concerning this proof for $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ from Gelfand's Trigonometry

[image]

Why is it true that $\frac{q}{d}=\frac{a}{d}$. Is it necessary to use properties of similar triangles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all. You simply use the fact that $q=a$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove $q=a$ using elementary geometry? I think I will upload a fuller version from the book.

Comment: Ay, I also misunderstood the picture, thank you! So $PD=q$ and $q=QP$.

Comment: @JamesWarthington No. $q=PQ$ and $p=DP$.

Comment: I can't help but mention [my own picture-proof of this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409), whose geometry is essentially the same as Gelfand's, but without the visual and cognitive clutter of overlapping triangles. I like to think that my figure is less prone to be misunderstand.

Comment: Hi Blue! Recognize you! I like your visual proofs very much! This particular proof for the formula is very neat. So I know like 4 proofs already. :)