# how to derive the sine and cosine angle difference identities graphically

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently learning trig identifies and on [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trig-equations-and-identities/using-trig-identities/a/trig-identity-reference), there is a graph demonstrating how sine and cosine addition identities are derived

[image]

I understand how each of the length is derived.

The author also mentioned

> A similar diagram could show the angle difference identities. Can you
>   draw one?

I can derive the sine and cosine angle difference identities algebraically.

Below is how I derive the sine angle difference identity. (by using the fact that `cos(-b) = cos(b) and sin(-b) = -sin(b)`)

[image]

But I'm not sure how to derive the sine and cosine angle difference identities graphically. Could someone please provide me with a hint?

Comment: See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409). (It's more than a hint!)

Comment: very helpful indeed. Thanks :)