# Why $\cos a\cdot \cos b+\sin a\cdot \sin b = \cos (b-a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I do not get why

$$\cos a\cdot \cos b+\sin a\cdot \sin b = \cos (b-a)$$

Thank you for your help

Comment: Various proofs here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html.

Comment: Idea: $\cos{x}=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin{x}=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following diagram by Blue demonstrates this perfectly:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Hence, we conclude

$$\cos(a\pm b) = \cos a\cos b\mp \sin a\sin b$$

You may want to check the following link.

- [How can I understand and prove the "sum and difference formulas" in trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry/1342#1342)

Comment: Thanks for giving me credit (you're learning! ;) ... but the proper thing to do in this case (for the sake of the Math.SE community) is to vote to close the question as a duplicate of the other, since the other one has lots of different answers.

Comment: Haha, I guess that was the better option of the two. :-) Will do!