# Why do these two triangles (PDB and OBC) have same alpha angle?

Tags: trigonometry

I am wondering how do these two triangles  (PDB and OBC) have same alpha angle?

[image: triangles]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you show your attempts? Or the question has a high chance to be closed.

Comment: I think you left too much to our imagination. We have to guess the construction

Comment: @culverkwan i was reading about why sin(a+b) is not equal sin(a)+ sin(b) in the following website https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/technical-mathematics-sixth/9780470534922/9780470534922_sum_or_difference_of_two_angles.html which i could not get how those mentioned triangles are equal.

Comment: @luciotanzini this is about the proof of sin(a+b) which is available at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/technical-mathematics-sixth/9780470534922/9780470534922_sum_or_difference_of_two_angles.html

Comment: so you don't need the two triangles to be equal, you only need the angle DPB to be equal to alpha

Comment: @luciotanzini good point! I edited the question. It is written that the angle between lines PD and PB is equal to the anle between  OB and OC lines. Why is that?

Comment: I like [my illustration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409) of the $\sin(a+b)$ identity better. :) If you look closely, you can deduce the answer to your question from it.

Comment: By the way ... If you want to convince yourself that $\sin(a+b)$ is generally not equal to $\sin(a)+\sin(b)$, consider $a=b=90^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $ADBC$ is a square the triangles are congruent by $ASA$

Otherwise there is not enough information to answer the question