# Why is the integral of harmonically related sinusoids either $\frac{T}{2}$ or $0$?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I'm taking a signals processing class and am trying to wrap my head around why the following is true.

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}kt)cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}mt) = \begin{cases}
                                   \frac{T}{2} & \text{if $k = m$} \\
                                   0 & \text{if $k \neq m$}
   \end{cases}$$

What does it mean(physically) for two sinusoids when they are multiplied with each other? Is there an easy way of visualizing that? What is the significance of $\frac{T}{2}$ when $k = m$?

Why is the above equation true physically/intuitively for signals?

Comment: It's helpful to recall some high-school trigonometry. Namely, look up the product-to-sum formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here -

Thanks to Semiclassical's answer I've decided to answer my own questions.

(Also for more insight on the trig identities check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/582205))

So we have $$\int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}kt)\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}mt)$$

We will use the following trigonometric formula $$\cos(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2}\left(cos(A+B) + cos(A - B)\right)$$

Applying that identity
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}kt)\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}mt)dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k+m)) + \cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k-m))\right)dt$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k+m))\right)dt + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k-m))\right)dt \right)$$

**Case 1: $k = m$**

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(2k))\right)dt + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\cos(0)dt \right)$$

Notice that the first term contributes $0$ because we are integrating cosine over an entire period and the "positive areas" and "negative areas" negate each other, while the second term is integrating $1$ over the period. Thus,
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(2k))\right)dt + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\cos(0)dt \right) \\ = \frac{1}{2} \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}dt = \frac{T}{2}$$

**Case 2: $k \neq m$**

From
$$=\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k+m))\right)dt + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 +T}\left(\cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}(k-m))\right)dt \right)$$

Both terms contribute $0$ since they are integrating a cosine wave over a full period with "negative" and "positive" areas

And of course, a similar argument can be made for sine waves.