# How to prove this cosine equation using these points on the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that: $$\cos(u+v) = \cos(u)\cos(v) - \sin(u)\sin(v)$$ using the fact that the distance from A to C is the same as the distance from B to D in the picture below:

[image: picture of the unit circle the problem refers to]

I tried using the laws of cosine and sine by looking at the triangles OBD and OAC (where O is the point at the center of the circle) but I never managed to get anywhere with these equations. The problem is taken from my math textbook and there is no solution to the problem there.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction of an answer while not giving the full solution?

Comment: Draw the altitudes from $A$ and $C$. Then Thales and Pythagoras in the triangles that appear.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the squares of the distances $CA$ & $DB$ using Pythagoras from the coordinates of $A,B,C,D$ ?

Comment: For a proof from another viewpoint, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4723650.

Answer (score 0):

The line segments $AC$ and $BD$ both have the same
central angle $u+v$ and hence the same length which
is $2\sin((u+v)/2)$. Now use the Cartesian
coordinates of $A = (\cos(u),-\sin(u))$ and
$C = (\cos(v),\sin(v))$ to find the distance between
them. Use the identity $\cos(x)=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$
with $x=u+v.$ The rest is easy algebra and trig.